# How to correctly switch view?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, switching, modalviewcontroller

i know its already allot of info about that in internet, but i'm new to programming and little confused, i need little help please... for example i have 10 views controllers and switching between it with a buttons for example i switching with

```
    -(IBAction)goToSecondView:(id)sender {

 SecondViewController *secondView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
 [self presentModalViewController:secondView animated:NO];
 [secondView release];
    }
   /* or */


-(IBAction)goToSecondView:(id)sender {

SecondViewController *secondView = [[SecondViewController alloc]
initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil]; [self.view addSubview:secondView.view];
[secondView release];
}
```

and after need if i switch to remove the first view with that:

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview]; /* or */ [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

and i dont know how to make remove the first view when i switching to second, for example when go from **FirstView** to **SecondView** the second view, need to remove the ***FirstView*** and after from **SecondView** go to **ThridView** or to **SevenView** example and need to remove the ***SecondView***... how can i do that?can you make a sample code please? i know its very easy but not for me, im new to programming

--------------------update-----------------------------------------------------------------

i want make something like > [here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/52107-how-correctly-switch-controller.html) < but i dont understand all, can any one make a sample code please?.

**Thank You Very Much**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which of those methods you use (or if you should use another) depends exactly on what you are trying to achieve.

If there was one view which listed all the other ones and all you wanted to do was go back and forth between the first view and another one then the presentModalViewController:otherView approach would be fine. If you are adding the other views as a subview of the first ones and completely covering it up, that is not the best way to do things. You should rather add the other view as a subview of the window (or the other views parent view) and then remove that view from the window/parent view using [theView removeFromSuperview];

If you have a hierarchical structure, i.e. you can go several layers deep, from the first view to the second, from it to the third, then you should look at using a UINavigationController. Each time you want to show a new view you push it onto the UINavigationController's stack, to go back a level you pop it off (if you use the default navigation bar with a back button this is taken care of for you). In this situation you don't have to deal with removing unseen views and recreating them when needed, thats all taken care of by the UINavigationController.

Comment: i wana make something like that, but i dont know how to make it correct

 SecondViewController *secondView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
 [self presentModalViewController:secondView animated:NO];
[FirstViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; //dismiss the current View when switching to another

Comment: dismiss the current view when i switching to another, for example first i go from FirstView to SecondView after i go from SecondView to FiveView and after again to SecondView, and i dont know how to make it to dismiss the current view when switching to another

Comment: If that's how you are doing it then you don't have to dismiss the view yourself, the os will take care of making sure that views that aren't visible aren't wasting more space than they need to.

Answer (score 0):

Remember also that you needn't always 'remove' views. You can hide them instead.

[self.view setHidden:YES]

This will just make them not be drawn. That's handy, because removeFromSuperview will actually release the view from memory unless it's been retained, meaning you'll never get it back.